# Better Solutions to Implementing global entity properties in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications, soap

I use classes to respond to PageMethods in some webpages. Asp.net engine automatically serializes the Class to JSON. I have few classes that have common properties like `"RequestState"-Enum` and `"Error"-String` which represent the State of the Request and the String describing the Error if any. For example look into this class below,

```
public  class Contacts
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public RequestState RequestState { get; set; }
    public string   Message { get; set; }
}
```

last two properties come in more than 4-5 classes. How do i abstract these properties so that they become common instead of declaring them in each class like how i do now. Interface could be possible i would like your ideas too for this, code snippet would be highly appreciated. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class MessageBase
{
    public RequestState RequestState { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}


public class Contacts : MessageBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @chritofr so inhering would be good way you suggest ?? any reasons

Comment: Hi - yep. Generally use inheritance when data can be abstracted to more general (MessageBase) from more specific (Contacts) classes. Use interfaces if there is some common behavior (methods) between the two which you'd like to depend on.

Comment: i would mark this as answer but will wait for some time more to see if a better answer pop's up. thanks for reminding my oop' basics duh :)

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you get any problems. :D